# Node.js install keeps rolling back install right near the end

Tags: javascript, node.js

Working on Windows 7 on a work computer that's been handled by many users before me. npm and node seems to have been installed in the past, particularly through other software downloads, but nothing is organized and I'm afraid to delete things because...well, it's a work computer and I'm liable to destroy something. Anyways, I've been trying to load node.js but it keeps rolling back. I've tried eliminating the option 'online documentation shortcuts' which was suggested in a similar questions in question, but no luck. Right near the end it starts to roll back.

I can't figure out where to get an error log so I can be more specific.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to figure out where to get an error log so you can be more specific :) Otherwise anyone who offers help would just be guessing.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response,but I don't know how to get an error log. Where do I find it?

Comment: You should try looking it up on the internet!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with installing node via NVM?

NVM is a Node Version Manager, it allows you to install multiple versions 
of node in separated environments

[Here is the link!](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)